How to return subtype and domain description instead of the code, when using arcgis.gis Python
I am working on some Python that takes an attribute table and makes a pandas df from it. I am doing this by creating an empty list, and looping through each record of the attribute table and making a dictionary for each row, which is then appended into that empty list and made into a df.
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.features import FeatureLayer
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

empty_list = []
for feature in value:
attribute_dictionary = {
            'ITEM_NUMBER': feature.attributes['itemnumber'],
            'UTILITY_TYPE': feature.attributes['utilitytype'],
            'UTILITY_SUBTYPE': feature.attributes['utilitysubtype']
}
empty_list.append(attribute_dictionary)
df = pd.DataFrame(empty_list)
df.set_index('ITEM_NUMBER', inplace=True)
print(df)

When I print the df, I see the subtype code and domain codes instead of the description. How can I get feature.attribute to get the description as opposed to the coded value?
(I have left out some code referencing my feature layers)

Can you show how you create the value variable

Here is some code I worked up to get a dictionary containing the code and description of all domains for a specified field in a published feature layer IF that layer has subtypes. There are several more steps required to get to the domains of a field if there are Esri subtypes being used as well.
###- Format of the output dictionary:

domain_dictionary = {'Code': 'Description'}

This could be modified to be used with a geodatabase I believe. Since, I do not expect my schema to change, I just needed this one dictionary. However, this could be easily implemented within other code if your schema changed frequently. I would be happy if this helps anyone that had my same issue.
Source code:
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.features import FeatureLayer

# Connect to your GIS (replace with your own credentials)
portal_url = ''         # - Portal connection
item_ID = ''            # - ID of Feature Layer
field_name = ''         # - Name of field containing the domain
layer_indices = [0]     # - Indices of the layers you want to get domains for

try:
    print('Connecting to GIS...')
    gis = GIS(portal_url)
    layer_items = gis.content.get(
        item_ID)
    all_layers = layer_items.layers
    print('Connected to GIS successfully.')
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Error connecting to GIS: {e}')
    exit()


def get_field_domain_info(layer, field_name, domain_dict):
    print(
        f"Checking domain information for field '{field_name}' in layer '{layer.properties.name}':")

    # Find the field in the layer's fields
    field_info = next(
        (f for f in layer.properties.fields if f.name == field_name), None)
    if not field_info:
        print(f"Field '{field_name}' not found in the layer fields.")
        return

    # Check if the field has a domain
    if hasattr(field_info, 'domain') and field_info.domain:
        domain = field_info.domain
        if domain.type == 'codedValue':
            for coded_value in domain.codedValues:
                domain_dict[coded_value.code] = coded_value.name

    # Check for subtypes
    if hasattr(layer.properties, 'subtypes'):
        for subtype in layer.properties.subtypes:
            if 'domains' in subtype and field_name in subtype['domains']:
                domain = subtype['domains'][field_name]
                if domain['type'] == 'codedValue':
                    for coded_value in domain['codedValues']:
                        domain_dict[coded_value['code']] = coded_value['name']


# Initialize the dictionary for domains
domain_dict = {}

# Iterate over the specified layers
for index in layer_indices:
    try:
        feature_layer = all_layers[index]
        print(f'\nProcessing layer at index {index}')
        get_field_domain_info(feature_layer, field_name, domain_dict)
    except IndexError:
        print(f'Layer at index {index} does not exist.')
    except Exception as e:
        print(
            f'An error occurred while processing layer at index {index}: {e}')

# Remove duplicate entries and sort the dictionary
unique_sorted_domain_dict = dict(sorted(domain_dict.items()))

# Print the resulting dictionary
print(
    f'\nDictionary created for {len(unique_sorted_domain_dict)} unique domains.\n\nDomains found:')
for code, name in unique_sorted_domain_dict.items():
    print(f'Code: {code}, Description: {name}')

print('\n\n')
print(unique_sorted_domain_dict)

